# Xcode 6 : Changing the Font for a Size Class

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to setup different fonts or some sort of font scaling in my Size Classes in Xcode 6 as listed by this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH12-SW1

The problem is I can't seem to get past Step #3 which says:

[image]

I do not see a + button.

Am I missing something or is the documentation wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very tiny (at least on Mavericks). Took me a moment to find it too.

Maybe this will help?

[image]